# Creating a new variable through loops in R

Tags: r, loops

Here is a made up dataset that consist of 1) the number of black marbles 2) the number of white marbles and 3) total marbles

```
white<- c(5, 6,3,5, 9)
black<- c(1, 3,7,5,2)
total<- c(6,9,10,10,11)
data<- data.frame(white, black, total)
```

If I wanted to make a loop that created two new variables perwhite, which is white/total and perblack which is black/total, what would I need to do?

Here is what i've tried so far

```
variables<- list("white","black")
newnames<- list("perwhite", "perblack")
for (i in 1:2) {
  data$newnames[i]<- data[,variables[[i]]]/data$total
}
```

I think the problem in the current syntax is the when I am trying to create a new column in the dataset.

Thank you!

Comment: `transform(data, x = white/total, y = black/total)` is one way. To do it programmatically, yeah, a loop is fine or `data[, unlist(newnames)] <- lapply(variables, function(x) data[[x]]/data$total)` -- just use vectors not `list()` to define your two objects, by the way.

Comment: The real problem is that you're trying `x$y[i] <-` which is not valid syntax. The right-hand side of `$` can only contain a bare name as a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
for( i in setdiff( names(data), "total" ) )
    data[paste0( "per", i )] <- data[i] / data["total"]
```

NOTE: I would caution against using `data` as a variable name, because it's a name for one of the built-in functions.